# Mac OS X - run shell script from the desktop GUI

Tags: shell, scripting, macos, desktop

You can create a shell script or a Python or Ruby script and run it on the Mac by using "Terminal" ... if you have Finder open, and you click on the icon for the file containing the source code of a saved shell script, is there a way to have that script run, instead of opening in my text editor ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes - just put a `.command` suffix on the script.

Note: make sure the script is executable, e.g.

```
$ chmod +x myscript.command
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a script that does not open a terminal window?

Answer (score 7):

Just another quick alternative is the tool platypus (http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus/). Free and good, but you can donate, if you want.

> Platypus is a developer tool for the Mac OS X operating system. It creates native Mac OS X applications from interpreted scripts such as shell scripts or Perl, Ruby and Python programs. This is done by wrapping the script in an application bundle along with a native executable binary that runs the script.

Answer (score 2):

just associate .sh files with Terminal.app

Comment: This makes the file non-portable (.sh files are opened by XCode, for instance).

Comment: Actually, it's not a terrible solution if you do a Finder -> Get Info -> Open with: -> Terminal (and NOT click the Change All... button).  You'd be changing the default only for this file itself.